Add custom text in string based on values specified in text vector in R
Let's say I have a vector of string values that looks something like:
vec_vals<-c("value1", "value2", "value3")

and a text string which at certain points may contain those values, something like:
text_string<-"value1 blah blah blah value2"

I am trying to add a value, let's say x. in the text_string in front of any of vec_vals that appear in the text_string, so in this case the desired result would be:
text_string_cleaned<-"x.value1 blah blah blah x.value2"

Thanks!

What did you try? Where are you getting stuck?

I have tried gsub and str_split, but nothing is working.

You could use the stringr package:
library(stringr)
vec_vals <- c("value1", "value2", "value3")
text_string <- "value1 blah blah blah value2"

# Create the pattern "(value1|value2|value3)" which in str_replace_all will detect 
#  all matches of value1, value2, or value3.
pattern <- paste0("(", paste(vec_vals, collapse = "|"), ")")

# Replace all occurrences of value1, value2, or value3 with .xvalue1, .xvalue2, or.xvalue3
str_replace_all(text_string, pattern = pattern, replacement = "x.\\1")

#output
"x.value1 blah blah blah x.value2"

The purpose of \\1 in a regular expression is to insert the exact text that was matched by the first group of characters enclosed in parentheses in the pattern into the replacement string.

I like the efficiency/cleanliness of this solution the most. Thank you!

If you have just plain letters in your vec_vals column, you can combine them into a single pattern and then use gsub to update the values. For example
combined_pattern <- paste0("(", paste(vec_vals, collapse="|"), ")")
gsub(combined_pattern, "x.\\1", text_string, perl=T)
# [1] "x.value1 blah blah blah x.value2"

The combined pattern becomes (value1|value2|value3) which matches any of those strings and the parenthesis captures the match so we can use \1 in the replacement to get the matched value.

This works, thanks for the solution.

If you want replacment at any value of your vector, you need to iterate:
My proposal would be:
vec_vals<-c("value1", "value2", "value3")
text_string<-"value1 blah blah blah value2"

for(i in vec_vals) {
  text_string <- gsub(i, paste("x.",i, sep=""), text_string)
}

print(text_string)


This works, thanks for the solution.
